# Vanilla Javascript: Remove toggle class from X element if I click on Y element with the same toggle class

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I'm currently working on a sidebar menu where I toggle the "selected" class on a category, which has the classname "sidebar-category".

With jQuery I can easily achieve my desired goal: after toggling the "selected" class (if I click on another category) the previous category gets the class removed and is then applied to the currently clicked category:

```
$('.sidebar-category').click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-category").not(this).removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

My problem is that for this project I cannot use jQuery and must use vanilla Javascript.

So far I can achieve the toggling easily, but I'm not sure how I can remove the class when clicking on another category using vanilla Javascript. This is my current code:

```
var selectCategory = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-category');

for (var i = 0, l = selectCategory.length; i < l; i++) {
  selectCategory[i].onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery code that removes the `selected` class is equivalent to a loop. So just write that loop in your event listener.

```
var selectCategory = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-category');

for (var i = 0, l = selectCategory.length; i < l; i++) {
  selectCategory[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      if (selectCategory[j] != this) {
        selectCategory[j].classList.remove("selected");
      }
    }
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your target environment supports ES2015 (or you transpile your code to support such an environment), a declarative approach using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be achieved with the following code:

```js
function toggleSelectedClass(event) {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-category'))
    .filter(element => element !== event.target)
    .forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('selected')
      element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', false);
    });

  event.target.classList.toggle('selected');
  const pressed = event.target.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true';
  event.target.setAttribute('aria-pressed', String(!pressed));
}
```

```css
.sidebar-category {
  padding: 5px;
}

.selected {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleSelectedClass(event)">
  <button type="button" class="sidebar-category selected" aria-pressed="true">Click</button>
  <button type="button" class="sidebar-category" aria-pressed="false">Click</button>
  <button type="button" class="sidebar-category" aria-pressed="false">Click</button>
  <button type="button" class="sidebar-category" aria-pressed="false">Click</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** `getElementsByClassName`  returns an `HTMLCollection`, *not* an array, so `Array.from` is required to use the array methods `filter` and `forEach`.

**Note 2:** Keep accessibility in mind when designing such a menu. A good reference for this is https://inclusive-components.design/toggle-button/.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using @Barmar's solution though as it's cleaner in code and fits nicely with what I already had written.

Comment: You're welcome, but clean code implies readability and maintainability, and nested `for` loops with single letter variables is not clean.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the **Events API** in JavaScript.

Using the `onClick=""` property of an HTML element we can construct a toggling system.

1. Create a function to handle the click action of the user and pass in the element that has been clicked as the parameter. `function toggle(element){...}`
2. Inside that element first fire off an event to clear the selected element(s) using the event named `clearselected` that will iterate through the elements and set the `selected` property to false. Thus, semantically deselecting the elements.
3. Change the `selected` property of the element passed in the onclick handler to true.
4. Update the user interface (UI) using an event called `updateui` that changed the selected element to its desired appearance, and all non-selected elements to their desired appearance using a for loop that iterates through all elements and looks at the `selected` property.

Down below I have a code snippet that uses vanilla JavaScript to create a toggle system on the UI. It has a very basic HTML that uses the same class names and adds very little CSS to make the demo easier to understand. I hope this is the thing you were looking for!

```js
// Set up the HTML elements in JavaScript
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0];
var sidebarCategories = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-category");

// Add an event listener for clearing the selected elements
sidebar.addEventListener("clearselected", function(e) {
  for(var i = 0; i < sidebarCategories.length; i++){
    sidebarCategories[i].selected = false;
  }
}, false);

// Add an event listener updating the UI to reflect changes
sidebar.addEventListener("updateui", function(e) {
  for(var i = 0; i < sidebarCategories.length; i++){
    var current = sidebarCategories[i];
    if(current.selected){
      current.textContent = "selected";
    }else{
      current.textContent = "";
    }
  }
}, false);

// Write a on click handler to handle the toggle
function toggle(element){
  var event = document.createEvent("Event");
  event.initEvent("clearselected", true, true);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  
  element.selected = true;

  var event = document.createEvent("Event");
  event.initEvent("updateui", true, true);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
.sidebar-category {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>Click the boxes to see the toggle in action</p>
  <div class="sidebar-category" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
  <div class="sidebar-category" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
  <div class="sidebar-category" onclick="toggle(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow toggling the currently selected item, like in his original jQuery snippet. I do prefer `addEventListener` over using the `onclick` attribute for production code though.

Comment: Only a small amount of conditional logic would be needed to accomplish that desired effect.